# How to add an Icon at the beginning of PopupMenuItem in flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a `PopupMenuButton` widget in which I want to add an icon at the beginning of each `PopupMenuItem`. I've been trying to find a way to do this but I'm not finding any.

```dart
Below is the **main.dart** file.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:practical_0/homepage.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue
      ),
      home: Homepage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the **home.dart** file. This is where I have implemented the PopupMenuButton. I want the icon to appear at the beginning of `PopupMenuItem` before the `text`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum WhyFarther { harder, smarter, selfStarter, tradingCharter }

class Homepage extends StatelessWidget {

  final double heightFactor = 600/896;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        return new Card(
          new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              PopupMenuButton<WhyFarther>(
               onSelected: (WhyFarther result) { setState(() { _selection = result; }); },
               itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<WhyFarther>>[
                const PopupMenuItem<WhyFarther>(
                  value: WhyFarther.harder,
                  child: Text('Working a lot harder'),
                ),
                const PopupMenuItem<WhyFarther>(
                  value: WhyFarther.smarter,
                  child: Text('Being a lot smarter'),
                ),
                const PopupMenuItem<WhyFarther>(
                  value: WhyFarther.selfStarter,
                  child: Text('Being a self-starter'),
                 ),
                 const PopupMenuItem<WhyFarther>(
                   value: WhyFarther.tradingCharter,
                   child: Text('Placed in charge of trading charter'),
                 ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it with a Row, like this :

```dart
PopupMenuItem<WhyFarther>(
  value: WhyFarther.harder,
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Icon(Icons.work),
      Text('Working a lot harder'),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: This solution, didn't seem to work at first, but when setting icon color to non white color - did the trick `Icon(Icons.home, size: 24, color: Colors.orange,),`

Comment: @mike123 That is because of your themestyling set to probably white as primary color and different background.

Answer (score 22):

I would actually suggest using a ListTile like this:

```
              PopupMenuItem<WhyFarther>(
                value: WhyFarther.harder,
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.work),
                  title: Text('Working a lot harder'),
                ),
              )
```

Checkout Flutter Gallery for a live example: https://gallery.flutter.dev/#/demo/menu